# MVC View Bind with form post and display data in the same page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

As I have started working on MVC application, I have one query for the same.

I have one `textbox` (for employee name as I want to retrieve data basis on this) in the page , I want to post the `form and get result of 'Employees' data` in the `same form.` (I want to show `grid type layout in the same form` just below to the `textbox`)

Could anybody have any idea about `how to post form and display data in the same page`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what do you have so far?  What's giving you trouble?

Comment: I have 1 textbox in the page and I am able to get the data of employees, but I can not persist my value which is last searched by user.

Comment: I want to persist searched value in the same textbox.

Comment: So after you search, your search term in the text box vanishes, correct?  How are you defining that textbox?  Are you using TextBoxFor bound to a model (sounds like you are not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `EmployeeController` with two Actions: `Index` and `AddEmployee`.

The `Index` action should retrieve your list of Employees and hand them to the View.  You can use ViewData or make the View strongly typed and include the model object in the return: `return View(employeeList)`

The `AddEmployee` action should contain the logic to add the new employee record, then redirect back to the Index action using `RedirectToAction`.  This is known as the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.  You should never have your users "land" on a POST response, as it can result in double form submissions.

In the Employee View: You need a form above and a grid (e.g. MVCContrib Grid) below.  The Action of the form should be the `AddEmployee` action of the `EmployeeController`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you're asking for, but it seems to me you are trying to mimic the post-back behavior of WebForms.

**Don't do that**.

You should NOT render views from post actions. If the user tries to refresh the result page, the post action will be executed again. This can result in duplicated data (in a database web front-end application, for instance).

You should use the PRG pattern. Please read [this](http://blog.iannelson.systems/an-mvc-gotcha-and-the-prg-pattern/), [this](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Using-Post2c-Redirect2c-Get-Pattern.aspx) or [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2008/08/22/prg-pattern-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx).